# How do I set SCTP_MAX_BURST for an association?

Tags: sockets, sctp

I am trying to set SCTP_MAX_BURST using the following code

```
struct sctp_assoc_value assocValue;
memset(&assocValue, 0, sizeof(assocValue));
assocValue.assoc_value = getMaxBurstValue();
setsockopt (fd, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_MAX_BURST, &assocValue, sizeof (assocValue));
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:
"No such file or directory"

Could anyone help me with the possible reason for the failure?

Answer (score 0):

The text you mention ("No such file..") is for ENOENT, 2, which isn't listed as a return for setsockopt on any of the Linux systems I have access to.

On my Redhat 5 system, I get back ENOPROTOOPT (errno 92) because the kernel hasn't implemented that socket option for 2.6.18's sctp.

Comment: When i changed the  IPPROTO_SCTP to SOL_SOCKET, I am not getting any error and I am bale to set the value and getsockopt is also showing whatever value I have set, But I m not sure is it a right way         setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOKCET, SCTP_MAX_BURST, &assocValue, sizeof (assocValue));

Comment: @jhon, According to RFC 6458, the socket does have to be many-to-one flavor:
   int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
and it is an SCTP-level option
   int rc = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_MAX_BURST, &assocValue, sizeof(assocValue));
By picking a different level, you are getting a SOL_SOCKET level option that just happens to have the same integer value as the SCTP-level enum.

Comment: -where exactly in RFC 6458 its mentioned that it has to be many to one flavor to set MAX_BURST? i was trying to find out but couldn't get that?

Comment: Now I don't know why I wrote that.  Maybe I was looking elsewhere or assumed from the title that you meant "for a specific association."  Perhaps I had a head wound.  Section 8, par. ~2-4 talks about the scope differences between 1-1 and 1-N, and doesn't mention that limit.